# Determining the proper amount of Neurons for a Neural Network

Tags: c#, neural-network

I have been doing some research with neural networks and the concept and theory as a whole makes sense to me. Although the one question that sticks out to me, which I haven't been able to find an answer to yet, is how many neurons should be used in a Neural Net. to achieve proper/efficient results. Including Hidden Layers, neurons per Hidden Layer, etc. Do more neurones necessarily more accurate results (while being more taxing on the system) or will less neurons still be sufficient? Is there some sort of governing rule to help determine those numbers? Does it depend on the type of training/learning algorithm that is being implemented into the neural net. Does it depend on the type of data/input that is being presented to the network?

If it makes it easier to answer the questions, I will most likely be using feedforwarding and backpropogation as the main method for training and prediction.

On a side note, is there a prediction algorithm/firing rule or learning algorithm that is generally regraded to as "the best/most practical", or is that also dependant on the type of data being presented to the network?

Thanks to anyone with any input, it's always appreciated!

EDIT: Regarding the C# tag, that is the language in which I'll be putting together my neural network. If that information helps at all.

Comment: *If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.*  http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask  Also, I don't see how this has anything to do with C#.

Comment: See http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/181/how-to-choose-the-number-of-hidden-layers-and-nodes-in-a-feedforward-neural-netw

Comment: @0xA3, great link. This question may not be specific enough for SO, but just a few thoughts: neural network size is dictated by the complexity of the function or classifier they represent. Also, yes, it is possible to have too many neurons: in classification it can lead to overfitting and loss of a generalized model.

Comment: Have you tried to follow Andrew Ng's courses regarding this topic? He provides some really good intuitions on how to do this. The layman's version is provided on www.ml-class.org and the more hardcore one can be found on youtube: http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLA89DCFA6ADACE599&feature=plcp

Comment: I haven't actually heard about his courses yet, but I will definitely give them a look. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I specialized in AI / NN in College, and have had some ameture experience working on them for games, and here is what I found as a *guide for getting started*. Realize, however, that each NN will take some tweaking to work best in your chosen environment. (One potential solution is to expose your program to 1000s of different NNs, setup a testable criteria for performance and then use a Genetic Algorithm to propagate more useful NNs and cull less useful NNs - but that is a whole other very large post...)

I found - in general

- Input Layer - One AN for each input vector + 1 Bias (always 1)
- Inner Layer - Double the Input Layer
- Output Layer - One AN for each Action or Result

Example: Character Recognition

- If you are examining a 10x10 grid for character recognition;
- start with 101 Input AN (one for each pixel, plus one bias)
- 202 Inner AN
- and 26 Output AN (one for each letter of the alphabet)

Example: Blackjack

- If you are building a NN to "win at blackjack";
- start with 16 Input AN (13 to count each occurance of a card, 1 for player hand value, 1 for dealer "up-card", and 1 bias)
- 32 Inner AN
- and 6 output AN (one for "Hit" "Stay" "Split" "Double" "Surrender" and "Insurrance")

Comment: I have very limited exposure to NN so far, so excuse me if this question very basic; but what do you mean by a Bias Inner Layer? A hidden layer that holds some bias? And what 'value' is the Bias layer set to? Also am I correct in assuming inner layer = hidden layer?

Comment: Sorry for confusion, by "Bias" I mean a single AN, in the Input Layer that is always set to 1. There is no need for Bias on the Inner or Output layers. (SO formatted my post differently than what I did, so the lines ran together when they should not have =p ) So, the Bias Artificual Neuron always feeds a "1" to the Inner Layer, as if it's a normal AN that's "stuck on."

Comment: So setting the bias input neuron as '1' will generally be favorable, regardless of the type of input being fed to the input layer? For example, aren't the types of input for character recognition and BlackJack different? Thanks again!

Comment: The input types aren't very different, really. For character recognition, the input will be 1 or 0 (is there a pixel in that location?), you add a +1 Bias AN (essentially a 101st pixel that is "stuck on"). In the case of Blackjack, the inputs will be an integer range, but you can still stick a binary AN there that is always set to "On." There is no particular reason why you can't mix and match input types in your Input Layer. Want to really blow your mind? There is no particular reason you have to have each AN use the same activation function - but that is another huge post!

Comment: So even if the input values can range from 0-100, setting the bias AN as 1 is still acceptable? Sorry for easking the same question over, but it is quite the concept to try and understand.

Comment: Another question, was there any particular method of training that you preferred or worked best in general? What about for prediction?

Comment: Yes, setting the bias AN to 1 is fine, even with an input range from 0 to 100 for other ANs, because each AN will have an inner activation function that takes into account the inputs and weights before determining their output. If ALL of your inputs are 0-100, you could set your Bias to 100, although mathematically it will end up the same when figured against the weight vector for the activation function. For instance, 100 (bias) X 0.01 (weight) = 1.0, 1 (bias) X 1.0 (weight) = 1.0.

Comment: For Learning Rules - try the Perceptron Learning Rule... http://sydney.edu.au/engineering/it/~irena/ai01/nn/6.html

Answer (score 1):

Some **general rules** are the following based on this paper: *'Approximating Number of Hidden layer neurons in Multiple Hidden Layer BPNN Architecture*' by Saurabh Karsoliya. Source [here](http://www.ijettjournal.org/volume-3/issue-6/IJETT-V3I6P206.pdf)

- The number of hidden layer neurons are 2/3 (or 70%
  to 90%) of the size of the input layer. If this is
  insufficient then number of output layer neurons can
  be added later on.
- The number of hidden layer neurons should be less
  than twice of the number of neurons in input layer.
- The size of the hidden layer neurons is between the
  input layer size and the output layer size.