# Layers and Neurons of a Neural Network

Tags: algorithm, neural-network

I would like to know a bit more about Neural Network, I'm developing a C++ program to make a NN but I'm stuck with the BackPropagation algorithm, sorry for not offering some working code. 
I know that there are so many libraries for creating a NN in many languages, but I prefer to make one from my self. The point is that I don't know how many layers and how many neurons should be necessary for achieving a particular goal such as pattern recognition, or functions approximations, or whatever.

 My questions are: if I'd like to recognize some particulars patterns, like in image detection, how many layers and neurons-per-layer should be necessary? Let's say my images are all 8x8 pixels, I would start naturally with an input layer of 64 neurons, but I don't have any idea of how many neurons I have to put in hidden layers, and also in output layer. Let's say I have to distinguish from cats and dogs, or whatever you may think, how could be the output layer? I can imagine an output layer with only-one neuron outputting a value between 0 and 1 with the classical logistic function (`1/(1+exp(-x)`) and when it is near 0 the input was a cat and when approaches 1 it was a dog, but ... is it correct? What if I add a new pattern like a fish? and what if the input contains a dog and a cat ( ..and a fish)? This make me thinking that the logistic function in the output layer is not very suitable for pattern recognition like this, only because 1/(1+exp(-x)) has a range in (0,1). Do I have to change the activation function or maybe add some other neurons to the output layer? Are there some other activations function more accurate to do this? Do every neurons in every layers have the same activation function, or it is different from layer to layer?

Sorry for all of this questions, but this topic is not very clear to me.
I read a lot around internet, and I found libraries all-yet-implemented and hard to read from, and many explanations to what a NN can do, but not how it can do.
I read a lot from https://mattmazur.com/2015/03/17/a-step-by-step-backpropagation-example/ and http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap1.html, and here I understood how to approximate a function (because every neurons in a layer can be thought as a step-function with a particular step for weights and bias) and how back-propagation algorithm works, but other tutorials and similars were more focused on preexisting libraries. I also read this question [Determining the proper amount of Neurons for a Neural Network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11193147/determining-the-proper-amount-of-neurons-for-a-neural-network) but I would like to involve also the activation functions of a NN, which is the best and for what is the best.

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: I think you will do better here if your questions are more focused and concise.  Also if you remove the C++ tag because this question has nothing to do with C++.

Comment: Why don't you try implementing backprop on a simpler model like logistic regression (essentially an ANN without any hidden layers), and then expand to more complicated models? Just a thought. Additionally, coursera (google it) is offering courses in DNN specializations from Stanford Prof Andrew Ng. Very Informative.

Comment: @Zroach thanks for your comments, I'll find out what Coursera offers about DNN. I wanted to know what are the main characters of a DNN and how I could construct one by achieving a particular goal. Anyway, starting with a simplified problem is the best approach.

Answer (score 2):

Your questions are quite general, so I can only give some general recommendations:

The number of layers you need depends on the complexity of the problem you want to solve. The more calculation is required to obtain an output from a given input, the more layers you need.

Only very simple problems can be solved with a single layer network. These are called linearly separable and are usually trivial. With two layers it gets better and with three layers, at least in theory, all kinds of classification tasks can be performed if you have enough cells within the layers. In practice, however it is often better to add a 4th or 5th layer to the network while reducing the number of cells within a single layer.

Be aware that the standard backpropagation algorithm performs badly with more than 4 or 5 layers. If you  need more layers, have a look at *Deep Learning*.

The numbers of cells within each layer mainly depends on the number of inputs and, if you solve a classification task, the number of classes you want to detect. In practice it is quite common to reduce the number of cells from layer to layer, but there are exceptions.

Concerning your question about the output function: In most cases you should stick with one type of sigmoid function. The case you describe is not really an issue because you could add another output cell for your "fish" class. The choice of a specific activation function is not that critical. Basically you use one whose values and derivative can be calculated efficiently.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So you mean that if I have to recognize 15 patterns I can add 15 output cells with sigmoid functions, don't you? Is there a rule or a method to know how many layers and cells per layers I have to put or is it just heuristic? If I exceed in layers, what are the algorithms used for training and upgrading weights in deep learning? Sorry for so opened questions, but I'm looking for figuring out how it's working

Answer (score 2):

@Frank Puffer has already provided some nice information, but let me add my two cents.  First off, much of what you're asking is in the area of [hyperparameter optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperparameter_optimization).  Although there are various "rules of thumb", the reality is that determining the optimal architecture (number/size of layers, connectivity structure, etc.) and other parameters like the learning rate typically requires extensive experimentation.  The good news is that the parameterization of these hyperparameters is among the simplest aspects of the implementation of a neural network.  So I would recommend focusing on building your software such that the number of layers, size of layers, learning rate, etc., are all easily configurable.

Now you specifically asked about detecting patterns in an image.  It's worth mentioning that using standard multi-layer perceptrons (MLPs) to perform classification on raw image data can be computationally expensive, especially for larger images.  It's common to use architectures that are designed to extract useful, spacially-local features (i.e.: [Convolutional Neural Networks](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/lenet.html) or CNNs).

You could still use standard MLPs for this, but the computational complexity can make it an untenable solution.  The sparse connectivity of CNNs for example dramatically reduce the number of parameters requiring optimization and simultaneously build a conceptual hierarchy of representations better suited for classification of images.

Regardless, I would recommend implementing backpropagation using stochastic gradient descent for optimization.  This is still the approach typically used for training neural nets, CNNs, RNNs, etc.

Regarding the number of output neurons, this is one question that does have a simple answer: use "one-hot" encoding.  For each class you want to recognize, you have an output neuron.  In your example of the dog, cat, and fish classes, you have three neurons.  For an input image representing a dog, you would expect a value of 1 for the "dog" neuron, and 0 for all the others.  Then, during inference, you can interpret the output as a probability distribution reflecting the confidence of the NN.  For example, if you get output dog:0.70, cat:0.25, fish:0.05, then you have a 70% confidence that the image is a dog, and so on.

For activation functions, the most recent research I've seen seems to indicate that [Rectified Linear Units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier_(neural_networks)) are generally a good choice since they're easy to differentiate and compute, and they avoid a problem that plagues deeper networks called the "vanishing gradient problem".

Best of luck!

Comment: Thank you so much, you make me curious about CNNs and how they works, maybe I could fine them more suitable for my goals. I'll learn more about Rectified Linear Units as you suggest. Thanks!